# I am receiving an error with my resizing / input array for a ConvLSTM model

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a data set with images of daily precipitation maps. I am trying to build a Precipitation Nowcasting model using ConvLSTM2D.

Please help me figure out how I can change the array’s shape to work.

Using this as a reference: https://github.com/wqxu/ConvLSTM/blob/master/radar_forecast.py

Please help me with this error:

```
Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_167_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1785, 400, 320, 3)
```

If I add another dimension to the reshape array of X_Train:

```
X_Train = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 400, 320, 1, 3)[:1785] # converting list to a numpy array
```

I get the following error [What happened to 1785?]:

```
Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_167_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 320, 1, 3)
```

If I add another dimension to the input_shape of the ConvLSTM2D input layer:

```
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(None, 400, 320, 1, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_5:expected ndim=5, found ndim=6
```

At the moment I am just trying to find any situation that actually works so I can go from there. Please help if you can.

Basically I want to know if the issue is in the number of dimensions of my arrays? If so how can I change it?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

DATADIR = "C:/Users/StephanIliffe/Documents/data"

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, "Input") # path to jpg precipitation maps
    class_num = 1
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (400, 320))
        training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  

create_training_data()

X = []
X_Train = []
X_Test = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)

X_Train = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 400, 320, 3)[:1785] # converting list to a numpy array
X_Test = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 400, 320, 3)[765:] # converting list to a numpy array

model = Sequential()

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, 400, 320, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta')
model.fit(X_Train, X_Test, batch_size=30, epochs=10, validation_split=0.05)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's exactly what the error says: `expected conv_lst_m2d_167_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 320, 1, 3)`. Your input data has four dimensions; it needs to have five: `(samples, time, rows, columns, channels)`.

Comment: Thanks Karl. Please look back at my question. If I add another dimension to the reshape of X_Train, it ignores the first dimension and still does not work? Maybe I am doing it wrong. I would like to know how I can make it 5 dimensional

Comment: What does `print(X_Train.shape)` give you?

Comment: (1785, 1, 400, 320, 3) if i use X_Train = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1, 400, 320,  3)[:1785]

Comment: Though I must admit the time element is a bit confusing to me. I don't think I'm adequately inputing a time parameter. But this is 5-dimensional?

Comment: Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_167_input to have shape  (None, 400, 320, 1), but got array with shape (1, 400, 320, 3)

Comment: Also not sure why I put a 3 in for the input shape at the end and it becomes a 1. It is a color image.

Comment: Hmmm, it could be the fact that you have only one frame in each batch (time=1) causes Keras to interpret it as 4d instead of 5d, but I can't be certain

Comment: It seems to work after changing the image to grayscale and the channels from 3 to 1? Any idea why this is?

Comment: The order of your channels seems to be switched around. The error `Error when checking input: expected conv_lst_m2d_167_input to have shape (None, 400, 320, 1), but got array with shape (1, 400, 320, 3)` seems to suggest this. What backend are you using? Try playing around with `data_format='channels_last'` and `data_format='channels_first'`

Comment: Thanks. You have given me a lot to think about. I'll mark this as the answer.